# Cannot get Grand Central Dispatch implemented correctly on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es

I'm trying to update and load a UIProgressBar while some code is running on a background thread. When the background thread has finished loading creating an avatar it should update the variable avatarFinishedLoading to TRUE which enables the code within the Open GL ES update method to begin to function.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgressBar) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    dispatch_queue_t loadAvatarAndFrames = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(loadAvatarAndFrames, ^{
        [self createAvatar];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            avatarFinishedLoading = TRUE;
        });
    });
}

- (void)updateProgressBar {
    float progress = [threadProgressView progress];
    if (progress < 1) {
        threadProgressView.progress = progress + (float)0.01;
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgressBar) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }else{
        [threadProgressView setHidden:TRUE];
    }
}


- (void)update
{
    // Set colour of background
    glClearColor(self.backgroundColour.x, self.backgroundColour.y, self.backgroundColour.z, self.backgroundColour.w);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (avatarFinishedLoading == TRUE){
       //Do Some Code
    }
}
```

The application is crashing with the error message: 0xf5a2503:  movzwl (%eax,%ecx,2), %eax
exec_bad_access

I cannot figure out where I am going wrong as it seems ok to me.

**EDIT**

It appears that I have a GL Error: 1280 when executing this code on the background thread. If I run the 'createAvatar' method on the main thread I do not get any GL Errors and the avatar renders as expected

Thanks

Comment: Is `avatarFinishedLoading` a class ivar? You would probably be better off using an atomic `@property` to protect against threading issues, but I don't *think* that would give you the error you're seeing. You might want to check that `loadAvatarAndFrames` is getting set to something non-nil.

Comment: I would avoid setting any of ivars in the block, as the block might only copy its value. I would call update method instead.

Comment: the `[self createAvatar];` and `avatarFinishedLoading = TRUE;` lines are running on _different threads asynchronously_. it could be a problem. by the way: what does to `–createAvatar` method do? who and when does call the `–update` method? are you doing something with the avatar in the true branch of `if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the way you set your ivar since that is done on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      avatarFinishedLoading = TRUE;
});
```

Is it possible you touch something in `-createAvatar` method that you should not touch on a background thread?

Comment: It appears that I have a GL Error: 1280 when executing this code on the background thread. If I run the 'createAvatar' method on the main thread I do not get any GL Errors and the avatar renders as expected